# In MongoDB, my foreach() loop only iterates once

Tags: javascript, mongodb, foreach

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong in the following code? I have a collection that has 100K documents in it. I run the following code and the forEach loop only iterates once. This, in spite of the fact that when I count the number of documents prior to running the forEach I know tht there are 100K in the cursor.

Why is the forEach running once and then exiting? Here is the code:

```
// connect to the database
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("photosharing");

var isThere = null;
var orphans = 0;
var imageNumber = 0;
var numOfImages = 0
var cursor = db.images.find();
var cursorFound = cursor.count();
cursor.forEach(function(doc){
    numOfImages=+1;
    imageNumber = doc._id;
    isThere = db.albums.find({images : imageNumber});

    if(!isThere){
         orphans=+1;
    }   
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
+=1
```

instead of this

```
=+1
```

Your loop is running. You're just reseting the output to 1 every run.

Comment: Glad to help. Those kinds of things are usually the hardest to see.

Comment: Hey I have been meaning to get back to you on this. Thanks for catching that.

The REAL problem with this code is:
if (!isThere)...

My assumption was that if a cursor doesnt have any docs in it that it will evaluate as null. Au contrar! haha nope.. I changed it to use count() and then checked to see if the count was zero,

That got me to where I wanted to go.

Comment: Ahh. I see. isThere is getting set to a database return object or array (even without values) and objects/arrays are truthy even when empty.